# How can I show a restaurant menu with my chatbot?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to create a chatbot that can take an order from customers. I'm using dialogflow NLP. I got stuck when coming across the concept of showing a menu to the customer. I'm trying to show the total amount of customer's order. Can you suggest me how I can do it? So far I've created an intent and entities on Dialogflow. I have created a webhook using flask that handles the response.

Comment: share your code. what you have tried so far

Comment: Have you used dialogflow before @OnkarMusale? I have only created webhook to respond and write order on file.

Comment: you need to write logic in your webhook and send it as a response to the user. try it and share the code if problem still comes.